# Implementing tree algorithms on top of Arc<RwLock<Node>> - returning a stack of RwLockWriteGuard

Tags: rust, concurrency, rwlock

I am new to Rust here. I am trying to build a concurrent btree and I'm struggling with implementing algorithms on the tree.

In this example, I used a simplified version of my tree where the `LatchNode`'s type is `Arc<RwLock<Node>>`. I would like to implement a method called `find_child` which not only finds the node with matching key in the tree, I also want a stack of `RwLockWriteGuard` for all the parent nodes on the way to the child. This way, we are confident that another concurrent operation won't mess up the search result.

```
pub struct Node {
    k: i32,
    children: Vec<Option<LatchNode>>,
}

type LatchNode = Arc<RwLock<Node>>;

pub fn find_child<'a>(
    root: LatchNode,
    k: i32,
) -> (RwLockWriteGuard<'a, Node>, Vec<RwLockWriteGuard<'a, Node>>) {
    let guard = root.clone().write().unwrap();

    let mut stack = Vec::new();
    stack.push(guard);

    loop {
        let temp = stack.last().unwrap();
        // for simplicity, we travese down first node in children
        let child = temp.children[0].clone();
        match child {
            Some(ref child_node) => {
                let child_guard = child_node.write().unwrap();
                if child_guard.k == k {
                    return (child_guard, stack);
                }
                stack.push(child_guard)
            }
            None => {
                panic!("No node found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am getting the error

```
cannot return value referencing local data `child.0`
returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
`child.0` is borrowed here -> refers to the line : Some(ref child_node) => {
```

Looking at the code, it seems like Rust compiler thinks `child_node` is a temporary variable. But I am confident that RwLock that `Arc` points to will exist even at the end of the function. How might I be able to fix this method?

Comment: Sorry it doesn't answer my question. Here the `guard` references an `Arc` instance that compiler thinks will be out of scope. Also, I am looking for a solution to what I'm trying to fix, not just an explanation.

Comment: It doesn't work for the same reasons though. The guard at `stack[n]` references the Arc from `stack[n-1]`, which is self referential.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean, that's a good point! In that case I think a recursive approach may be what I want to simulate a stack but not store them in the same stucture

Comment: Recursion is the way to go. And you're much better off just cloning the `Arc`'ed node and returning that than trying to keep all the locks alive so you can return a reference.

Comment: dumb question but if I return a cloned `Arc` instead of the `lock` wouldn't a concurrent operation be able to modify the node I have returned since the `lock` is out of scope and released?

Comment: Yes, the lock will be released when the guards are dropped when the function returns. If that's an issue, an alternative is to pass in a `FnOnce` that does the operation on the node while the locks are held.